# I am getting a error because my value is Text and it is looking for a Numeric Value how do I fix this?

Tags: excel, vba

I am not a VBA programmer and I need help.
In my spreadsheet my Location (ComboBox1) is text and I can not change it to be numeric.  How do I fix it so it will use the Text.  I guess I need to use the IsText function but I can not figure out how.

My code is pasted below.  The first line after GetData() is where it stops.

```
Dim Loc As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, flag As Boolean

Sub GetData()

If IsNumeric(UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value) Then
    flag = False
    i = 0
    id = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value

    Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

        If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
            flag = True
            For j = 2 To 3
                UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = Cells(i + 1, j).Value
            Next j
        End If

        i = i + 1

    Loop

    If flag = False Then
        For j = 2 To 3
            UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
        Next j
    End If

Else
    ClearForm
End If

End Sub
Sub ClearForm()

For j = 1 To 3
    UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value = ""
Next j

End Sub
Sub EditAdd()

Dim emptyRow As Long

If UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
    flag = False
    i = 0
    id = UserForm1.ComboBox1.Value
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

    Do While Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ""

        If Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = id Then
            flag = True
            For j = 2 To 3
                Cells(i + 1, j).Value = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value
            Next j
        End If

        i = i + 1

    Loop

    If flag = False Then
        For j = 1 To 3
            Cells(emptyRow, j).Value = UserForm1.Controls("TextBox" & j).Value
        Next j
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `If Not IsNumeric...` ???

Comment: If Not IsNumeric does not work.

Comment: A ComboBox stores everything as a "text string", i would suggest that you place the ComboBox value into a cell, format the cell as a number, and set the "IsNumeric(cell.value), not the Combobox value.

Comment: Did not work.  Is there no way to replace IsNumeric with IsText